# Hardware Bringup - install uboot in fresh board

Tags: linux, embedded, bsp

I am very well aware about Linux on native and embedded system. I have ported BSP to mini2440 and Pandaboard. I have also cross compiled several packages for x86 and arm board including customization of VLC from the source code.

Well what I want to know is suppose if there is a fresh board (newly arrived after the manufacturing process), then how to bring it up for running Linux, I know first I  have to port Uboot or any boorloader, but for that one must know the address size of the Flash memory.

My question is suppose there is fresh board then How can i port uboot into the board assuming that I do not have any information about the address, the board has just come from the manufacturing process. Like many companies are giving services such as Chip Bring up and Board bring up, but which information is require to bring it up?

Talking about the mini2440 and pandaboard, we can get support from the companies, but suppose any if any new company wants to port Android/Linux, what information will require or How to Port the Boot loader then Linux/Android?

Summerize my question as per
1. How to port Uboot into fresh board?
2. How to port Kernel into the board?
3. How to do Chip bring up into the board?

I want to learn new things and wants to go one step ahead than BSP porting to the board.

Look forward to hear from the experts.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I have some working experience in bring-up fresh new board. My answer will be:
(1)One should be familiar with the Hardware design, such as one should be familiar with the schematics;
(2)In the UBoot source tree, choose one demo board which is similar with the fresh new board. Start to bring up based on it;
(3)The same for Linux Kernel;

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Q3:

> How to do Chip bring up into the board

If you have access to a JTAG (or otherwise-attached) debugger, you can load a full-blown 
kernel and then use the standard user-space tools and attachments to continue on.  For example, use ftp to pull the flash image from a server, and mtd-utils to write the flash (for example using `flash_erase` and `nandwrite`)

Comment: but to write it to flash memory, I need to know the flash address, block size etc. without the information how can i flash the memory no matter I have compiled all the mtd tools? Please let me know.

Comment: Well, yes, you need to know that.  Which means you need to find it out. Ask the board designers?

Comment: Thank you. So it means I will need the data from the board designer.

Comment: Afraid so, you can't bring up a board without knowing what's soldered onto it :)

Comment: Ok. got it. And that details are used to create device driver.

Comment: I'm using flash_erase and  nandwrite to load a new kernel in my mini-2440. Although everything seems ok, when I reboot and check the kernel version (uname -v) it hasn't changed. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

In mini2440 there is NOR flash with supervivi bootloader (from samsung). This will help in loading UBOOT to NAND flash.

If we have new board with NOR flash, first we should look for some tool with which we can flash on NOR, then we can see how we can flash Uboot on to NAND.

If we do not have NOR on the new board, then I am not sure, as far as I know we cannot execute instruction directly from NAND, it has to be loaded on to RAM.

I am working on same things (bringing up new board) on weekends. I will let you know if I have something further.

Also please correct/add your comments if you have more information.

Thanks,
Harish

Comment: Hi Harish, Infact I am using mini2440 board and I have ported Uboot to the board, I look forward to hear more from you about your experiment. What I was looking for was suppose If we have some fresh board from the manufacturer, how to port uboot and kernel to the board for product development. Thank you for your time. Look forward to hear about your experiement